# Enable and configure OPUS codec on PJSIP 2.5.1 on Android

Tags: android, sip, voip, pjsip, opus

I'm building a VOIP application on Android using PJSIP library.

I was trying to enable OPUS codec since OPUS was supported in PJSIP from v2.5.

I've followed the following [link](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1904) to configure OPUS on PJSIP.

I inserted `#define     PJMEDIA_HAS_OPUS_CODEC   1` in config_site_sample.h file to enable the OPUS codec.

But when I was trying to build PJSIP, I was getting the following error

```
../src/pjmedia-codec/opus.c:31:23: fatal error: opus/opus.h: No such file or directory
 #include <opus/opus.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
```

Am I doing anything wrong? What is the actual procedure to enable OPUS codec in PJSIP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set the compiler-flag `--with-opus=[absolute-path-to]/opus-dev-lib` like described here: https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1904

Don't change the static variables in the source code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll try it and update you on the same.

Comment: I followed the steps and got the following error during the pjsip 2.5.1 build. I was using opus-1.1.3.

Comment: jni/../celt/entcode.h:112: error: undefined reference to '__clzsi2'
jni/../src/opus_decoder.c:412: error: undefined reference to '__clzsi2'
jni/../src/opus_decoder.c:815: error: undefined reference to '__gnu_thumb1_case_sqi'
jni/../celt/mathops.h:151: error: undefined reference to '__clzsi2'
jni/../celt/kiss_fft.c:548: error: undefined reference to '__gnu_thumb1_case_uhi'
jni/../silk/Inlines.h:123: error: undefined reference to '__aeabi_lmul'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: The issue got fixed by upgrading to pjsip-2.5.5. Thanks.

Comment: @SamikBandyopadhyay  Did you resolve the problem for enabling opus codec into pjsip ?

Comment: I followed the following link to fix the issue on PJSIP 2.5.5: https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1904